# Смартфон видит @media (min-height) только в режиме: Версии для ПК

Tags: css

Смартфон не видит

```
@media (min-height: 1280px) { 
   div.mySlides img {
   width: 80%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Однако стоит в браузере телефона включить опцию: "Версия для ПК" и медиа-запрос срабатывает корректно!
Это относится ко всем типам мобильных устройств на которых я просматривал сайт.
Помогите пожалуйста!
Похожих ответов не нашёл...

Comment: Попробуйте
@media all and (min-heigth: 1280px)

Comment: В `head` прописано `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. 
Да, в head прописано всё верно!

Comment: Надо смотреть весь css. Или продемонстрируйте это поведение CSS в песочнице.

Comment: а у вас смартфон имеет 1280px ?

Comment: @MaximLensky большинство современных смартфонов имеют больше 1280px по высоте, по широте может и не все, но по высоте меньше 1280px - это уже дисплей смарт-часов.

Comment: @DiD согласен ..а физически какой имеет разрешение ?

Comment: Дисплей 720×1480.  Я пробовал на нескольких смартфонах, везде одни и теже симптомы. Локально в браузере весь адаптив работает нормально: тестировал на разных разрешениях. Но уже в интернете некоторые моменты работают некорректно. Интересует больше всего описанная мною проблема.

Comment: вот и делайте от 720 только ширины а не высоты -

Comment: Физически экран 5,6" 18,5:9 если вы об этом. Спасибо всем за советы, буду воевать дальше!

Comment: физические пиксели не обязательн сооответствуют программным - браузерным. Проще всего это проверить, написав простую HTML, в которой задать, например, разный цвет фона с помошью медиа-запросов для разных высот, например, с шагом в 50 пикселей. По результату можно будет судить, что там на самом деле. И, да, кто говорит ,что меньше 1280 по высоте, это уже не телефон - зажрался. Глаз прекрасно видит все при  разрешении 1/2 FullHD (540*960) при размере в 6 дюймов - это то же самое, что фуллхд дисплей 12-дюймового ультрабука, на которые почему-то никто никогда не жалуется.

Comment: Я с адаптивной версткой работаю впервые, не ожидал что в web-е результат окажется отличимым от локальной версии. Скорее всего сильно наплодил брейкпоинтов , попробую всё привести в порядок , оптимизировать. Не хочу забивать голову вам. Просто подумал что пропустил что-то очевидное. Попробую переделать отталкиваясь от ширины 720px а не от высоты экрана!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за подсказку, этот ответ был верным:

вот и делайте от 720 только ширины а не высоты - – MaximLensky 11 часов назад

Возможно смартфон не верно определял ориентацию экрана при @media (min-height: 1280px)
А при включении опции: "версия для ПК" понимал ориентацию экрана так как будто я наблюдаю десктопную версию.